# How to change window title on a new popup window with custom height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

Below is my code using a onclick with target="popup", how do I change the title of the new popup?

```
<a href="#" target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('http://s.jiathis.com/qrcode.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest12345.com','popup','width=220,height=220,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); return false;">Open new window</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the newly opened window:

```
var winRef = window.open(...);
winRef.document.title = 'Custom title';
```

The popup must have the same origin (domain name) as the opener, or at least have proper CORS header set. Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c7x7ajv2/

Comment: That did not work. I put
<script>var winRef = window.open(my_url);
winRef.document.title = 'Custom title';</script> right after my link.

Comment: @user3108698 I updated my answer with more info and an example.